# How you can connect between flutter and owncloud

Tags: flutter, dart, owncloud

I want to connect my Flutter project with owncloud on my server. How do I do this? What do I study so I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Own Cloud External API](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/developer_manual/core/apis/externalapi.html). It allows third party developers to access data provided by ownCloud apps.